# SUbstiute for SubQuery to delete records from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I'm using this query to delete unique records from one table.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID form TABLE 2)
```

But the problem is that both the tables have millions of records and using subquery will be very slow.

Can anyone tell me any alternative.

Comment: Depends on your indexing strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Delete t1 
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: Doesn't MySQL optimise `NOT IN` anti-joins to be as efficient as `OUTER JOIN / IS NULL`?  See [@Quassnoi's analysis](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/): "*The algorithms are in fact the same ... and the queries complete in same time.*".

Answer (score 0):

SubQuery are really slow infact [joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) exists!

```
DELETE table1 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting millions of records from a table always have performance issues; you need to check if the table has -
1. Constraints
2. Triggers, &
3. Indexes

on it. These things will make your delete even slower...

Please disable them before this activity. You should also check ratio of the "to be deleted" records to the entire table volume. If the number of records to be deleted is more than 50% of the entire table volume then you should consider below approach -

1. Create a temporary table containing records that you want to retain from the original table.
2. Drop the original table.
3. Rename temporary table to original table.

Before going for the above approach, please make sure that you have a copy of the definition of each of the objects dependent on this original table like the constraints, indexes, triggers etc. You may also need to check if the table that you are going to delete has any children.

Once this activity is complete, you can enable the constraints, indexes, triggers again!

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: Be careful when disabling indexes: some may well make dramatically speed up this operation.  Also be careful when disabling constraints and triggers: they may be essential for maintaining data consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Looking at the question I supposed that the user wants to delete millions of records and deleting such a huge volume does not happen everyday.. that is the reason I assumed it to be a one time activity and suggested to disable indexes and constraints

Comment: But indexes on `id` within the respective tables will be of *dramatic* assistance.  Disabling those indexes would be a terrible idea.

Comment: We implemented this approach in our project while purging one of the tables after going through this link - 

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689

Comment: I missed to add there that we need to enable everything once our one time delete activity is completed.